# How should I select top 10% of the table?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need the select the top x% rows of a table in Pig. Could someone tell me how to do it without writing a UDF?

Thanks!

Comment: If it deserves a down-vote, I deserve to know what is the obvious answer to this question. I would respect it if you would oblige.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I strongly believe this is the ca(u)se: [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but srsly, I can answer what I have tried. In fact, to be honest, I seem to have more idea about the problem than the good person who responded below (and he has a lot more points on reputation) as evidenced in my comment. Frankly, I've seen similar arrogant behavior on this website before. The assumption that short questions are dumb is obnoxious.

Comment: Also, finding median is an open problem and people try to do it heuristically. In a sense, this question is similar to that. But anyways, thanks for showing the respect to respond Cihat. Its rare.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, first you need to count the number of rows in your table and then obviously you can do:

```
A = load 'X' as (row);
B = group A all;
C = foreach B generate COUNT(A) as count;
D = LIMIT A C.count/10; --you might need a cast to integer here
```

The catch is that, [dynamic argument support for `LIMIT` function was introduced in Pig 0.10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2570). If you're working with a previous version, then [a suggestion is offered here](http://grokbase.com/t/pig/user/124aespn4n/limit-operator-doesnt-work-with-variables) using the `TOP` function.

Comment: C happens to be a bag of tuples, right (even though its got only one record)? I'm not sure how it works. I ran it and I notice that some records are missing

Comment: C is a bag of tuples (which can be cast to scalar). Just call `describe` on it to see for yourself. If you have `null` values `COUNT` will not count them, use `COUNT_STAR` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would go about pulling a percentage, but if you know your table size is 100 rows, you can use the LIMIT command to get the top 10% for example:

```
A = load 'myfile' as (t, u, v);
B = order A by t;
C = limit B 10;
```

(Above example adapted from http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/cookbook.html#Use+the+LIMIT+Operator)

As for dynamically limiting to 10%, not sure you can do this without knowing how 'big' the table is, and i'm pretty sure you couldn't do this in a UDF, you'd need to run a job to count the number of rows, then another job to do the LIMIT query.

Comment: Well. You can count the number of records using a GROUP ALL and then a subsequent COUNT inside a FOREACH. I don't know how to proceed from there. Also, passing the count and the bag to the UDF is trivial.

Comment: What i'm saying is you i don't think you can do this all in a UDF, without first taking the steps suggested (by yourself and @Chihat) to pre-position the data

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the pig code as it will take a while to write and test, but I would do it like this (if you need the exact solution, if not, there are simpler methods):

1. Get a sample from your input. Say a few thousand data points or so.
2. Sort this and find the n quantiles, where n should be somewhere in the order of the number of reducers you have or somewhat larger.
3. Count the data points for each quantile.
4. At this point the min point of the top 10% will fall into one of these intervals. Find this interval (this is easy as the counts will tell you exactly where it is), and using the sum of the counts of the larger quantiles together with the relevant quantile find the 10% point in this interval.
5. Go over your data again and filter out everything but the points larger than the one you just found.

Portions of this might require UDFs.