# hadoop pig return top 5 rows

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to return the top 5 rows of a group.
Basically I have a table with some state names and their cities which is grouped by state name. I want to have the top 5 cities of that state and not all of them.

How can I do this using pig?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I select top 10% of the table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700003/how-should-i-select-top-10-of-the-table)

Comment: @ChrisGerken I don't think this is exactly the same. He's doing a grouping first, THEN doing a top x. Did I understand the question?

Comment: @DonaldMiner: The key is the use of LIMIT in both cases

Comment: Exactly I have grouped my data first. What do you mean both cases?

Answer (score 11):

After a `GROUP BY`, inside of a `FOREACH`... you can do an `ORDER BY` first, then `LIMIT`. This will sort the things in each group first by city size, then pulls the top 5.

```
B = GROUP A BY state;
C = FOREACH B {                          
   DA = ORDER A BY citysize DESC;                
   DB = LIMIT DA 5;                         
   GENERATE FLATTEN(group), FLATTEN(DB.citysize), FLATTEN(DB.cityname);
}
```